# Cookies persist in supertest/superagent test, but the user doesn't stay logged in

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, passport.js, superagent

## My Goal

I'm trying to use supertest's `agent` function in a jest `beforeEach()` to login the user before each test, as I want each test to run under the assumption that the user is signed in. For authentication, I am using passport and passport-local.

---

## This is what I tried (with parts cut out for brevity):

Test file:

```
import { agent, SuperAgentTest } from 'supertest';
import app from '../../src/app';

// create a `testRequest` variable to use in the tests
// that will be refreshed in between
let testRequest: SuperAgentTest;

const fakeUser = { email: 'john@john', username: 'john', password: 'john' };

beforeEach(async () => {
  // create new agent
  testRequest = agent(app);

  // register and login
  await testRequest.post('/register').send(fakeUser).expect(302);

  // other irrelevant stuff...
});

// protected route
describe('POST /campgrounds/new', () => {
  it('returns 200 OK', () => {
    return testRequest.get('/campgrounds/new');
  })
});
```

`/register` route:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { password, ...details } = req.body;
  try {
    // I am using passport-local-mongoose for this function-
    // it just registers the user
    const user = await User.register(new User(details), password);
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      // error handling and redirect
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // error handling
  }
})
```

---

## This is my result

Instead of a 200 status, I get a 302 status, meaning I was redirected to the login page. To debug this, I created a test route called `/current` which will log the current user and session ID cookie. I then sent a `GET` request to this route in both the `it` and `beforeEach` function respectively.

Interestingly, they both logged the same session ID, but only the request in `beforeEach` had a user object attached to the request.

Comment: What is inside your req.login() method. Please post that also

Comment: `req.login()` is a method automatically attached via passport. https://www.passportjs.org/docs/other-api/

Comment: Check your frontend is sending the credentials along with request. May be request to servers is not sent with cookies which contains the session. For reference look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_include. Let me know if problem exists

Comment: I already said that both requests share the same cookies

Comment: Try replacing req.login code with this ```req.logIn(user, (err)=>{if(err) return next(err); return next()});```

Comment: There's no middleware after besides the error handler, and I'm handling the errors myself anyways, so I don't see why that would help

Comment: Can you include the `/campgrounds/new` route?

Comment: @DanLevy It basically just checks if `req.isAuthenticated()` is true (which just checks if `req.user` exists). If so, it redirects to the login page. If not, it renders an ejs form.

Comment: I added more of an explainer to my answer below. Incl. how the plumbing works in passportjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### #1 Ensure body parser correct order

Make sure you have this before any routes or auth-related things.

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

#### #2 Check Passport Middleware Wire-up

Ensure you call `app.use(passport.initialize())` & `app.use(passport.session())` before any `app.use('/', aRouter)`, `router.get`, `router.post`, etc:

```js
// Set up session w/ specific config
app.use(session({
  secret: 'bquyqueajhbd',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new FileStore({path: '/tmp/session'})
}));
// Wire up the 
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

#### EDIT: Notes on `req.user`

Passport is designed to store the user ID in session.

Every request to the server must reload the user from the database.
This is the job of the middleware `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()`.

The logic there will call `passport.deserializeUser` to lookup the user by ID - the same ID that was saved upon login into the session by `passport.serializeUser`.

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id); // <-- Here's where the ID is saved to session.
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user); // <-- Here is where the `req.user` get's it's value from.
  });
});
```

> To debug this I'd focus on the `passport.deserializeUser` callback, add logs before and after the DB query.

(Note: it's been a few years since I taught this. Appologies if I'm not using the precise terms, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I'll start another round of debugging. One question: is [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) not needed anymore? I thought `bodyParser.json()` was better than `express.json()`

Comment: IIRC, bodyParser was removed around Express v2-3 and re-added in the main package in recent versions.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! After debugging `deserializeUser()` I found the problem! Suprise, surprise, it turns out the "other irrelevant stuff" in my `beforeEach()` function wasn't as irrelevant as I thought (it's a tale as old as time). I was deleting everything in my test database each time so that tests are individual, which obviously deleted the user from the database. idk how I didn't notice this! Enjoy your upvote, accepted answer, and bonus 100 rep for the help :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear @Lioness100!!